# linear trends in SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro

how do you exclude variables when printing proc freq in SAS? I want to bring all my variables with the exception of 3

Also trying to conduct linear trend for my variables age and s1, but continually getting errors

```
proc glm data =draft.data;

class q1;

model age = s1 / solution;

estimate "Linear trend for s1" s1 -3 -1 1 3;

contrast 'linear' s1 -3 -1 1 3;
;
run;
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example. Please provide also the error you are getting.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time, include the code you ran and error you received, as well as what you're trying to achieve. If you don't include the errors it could be anything and we have no idea where to start answering your question.

Comment: Guidelines on how to ask a question can be found here [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the variables you want to use directly in the FREQ procedure:

```
proc freq data=sashelp.cars;
  tables origin make;
run;
```

If you have a lot of variables, you can make use of the `drop` option.

```
proc freq data=sashelp.cars(drop=origin make);
run;
```